# removing duplicates, dplyr removes non-duplicated rows.

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to add rows to a dataframe and then check/remove rows that have a duplicated value in a single column of a dataframe. The end goal is to essentially have a row in the dataframe overwritten if new values for it are provided. I haven't been able to figure out how to dynamically specify rownames with dplyr (or with R at all really) so I'm doing it this way.

I start off with a test data frame and use dplyr to remove the first set of rows where the column position is duplicated like this:

```
    testData.df<-data_frame(Position=c("B1","B2","B3","B1","B2","B3"), rep=c("B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6"),name=c(rep("wibble",each=6)),status=c(rep("unknown", each=6)))
    testData.df <- testData.df %>%
      filter(duplicated(Position))
    testData.df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Position   rep   name  status
     <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
1       B1    B4 wibble unknown
2       B2    B5 wibble unknown
3       B3    B6 wibble unknown
```

This is as I would expect it to be. When I then run the same filter again, I get this:

```
testData.df <- testData.df %>%
  filter(duplicated(Position))
testData.df
# A tibble: 0 x 4
# ... with 4 variables: Position <chr>, rep <chr>, name <chr>, status <chr>
```

Why on earth is it removing rows which are not duplicated? Running it the first time, implies that it's working, as intended, i.e. it removes actual duplicates. I'm at a loss to explain the difference in behaviour the second time round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expecting `filter(duplicated(...))` to keep non-duplicated rows but it's actually doing the opposite. You can see this if we add `row_numbers` to each row

```
testData.df<-data_frame(Position=c("B1","B2","B3","B1","B2","B3"), rep=c("B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6"),name=c(rep("wibble",each=6)),status=c(rep("unknown", each=6))) %>%
               mutate(rn = row_number())
testData.df <- testData.df %>%
                  filter(duplicated(Position))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Position   rep   name  status    rn
     <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <int>
1       B1    B4 wibble unknown     4
2       B2    B5 wibble unknown     5
3       B3    B6 wibble unknown     6
```

You should instead used `filter(!duplicated(...))`

---

*Edited*

Try this instead to keep the duplicated row the first time, but not lose it the second time

```
testData.df<-data_frame(Position=c("B1","B2","B3","B1","B2","B3"), rep=c("B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6"),name=c(rep("wibble",each=6)),status=c(rep("unknown", each=6))) %>%
                mutate(rn = row_number())

run1 <- testData.df %>%
        group_by(Position) %>%
        slice(n()) %>%
            ungroup()

run2 <- run1 %>%
        group_by(Position) %>%
        slice(n()) %>%
            ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Position [3]
  Position   rep   name  status    rn
     <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <int>
1       B1    B4 wibble unknown     4
2       B2    B5 wibble unknown     5
3       B3    B6 wibble unknown     6
```

Comment: That twisted the brain a bit. That works thanks. Would you know how to get it to keep the latter rows, rather than the first instances of the duplicates? i.e. get it filter(!duplicated(Position)) to keep rows 4,5,6 rather than 1,2,3

Comment: @Ben if you want to keep duplicated rows, you can use your original code, but then you run into the issue of losing those rows with a 2nd execution of the same code. I'm a bit confused why you're running `filter(duplicated(...))` twice and why you want to keep the duplicated row the 1st time but not the 2nd time.

Comment: The code is being executed in a shiny app every time someone hits a button, so it gets run multiple times. It's constructing a map to be fed into a robot so that we can track which position each sample is in. If they re-enter the data for a particular row, I'd like to overwrite the data already there. There's probably an easier/better way to do it, via shiny was the easiest/quickest way for me to get an interface up though.

Comment: Guessing a bit what you're looking for, see my edited answer

Comment: Ta muchly. That does work. Though I've just found duplicated has a fromLast parameter, set that to true and it does what I'm looking for as well.